# Divs not aligned though they are inline-blocks

Tags: html, css, alignment

The problem is that both boxes are not aligned on the same height even though they have the same content.

When I target any individual div by using `margin-top` the entire main section moves up or down. Why is it happening even though I used inline-block:

```css
.box-1 {
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  color: whitesmoke;
  width: 45%;
  border-width: 5px;
  height: 194px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 101px;
}

.box-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid plum;
  background-color: powderblue;
  color: black;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  width: 33%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 62px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="box-1">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>lorem30</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <h1>Bye-Bye World</h1>
    <p>lorem30</p>
  </div>

</main>
```

[image]

PS: Making their width the same sort of solves the problem but not really as divs are almost aligned but they don't move up/down individually.

Comment: `dispaly-inline` block aligns the element depending on the line-height. If you want to horizontally align the elements you should consider flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure i understood your problem. do you want the two divs to be aligns right next to each other horizontally ? or vertically ?
you can use flex for this kind of stuff.
give this style to your main tag:

```
main{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}
```

this will align them horizontally. for vertical alignment add this :

```
flex-dirextion:column;
```

Comment: yes, I wanted them to be aligned next to each other horizontally.

Comment: Right. I found another way one can algin without using flexbox. It is just wrapping  "box-1" & "box-2" divs in separate divs individually and then targeting those new divs for horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 1):

It's the css for the individual boxes. you have assigned a fixed height to box one. not to the second box. i have added a third class and added the height there and assigned it to both boxes.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 194px;  
}

.box-1 {
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    color: whitesmoke;
    width: 45%;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 194px;  
    margin-right: 101px;
}


.box-2 {
    
    border: 2px solid plum;
    background-color: powderblue;
    color: black;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    width: 33%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 62px;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="style.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="box-1 box">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <p>lorem30</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-2 box">
            <h1>Bye-Bye World</h1>
            <p>lorem30</p>
        </div>

    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, missed it.